# Flask-Script add_option method not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-script

Using flask-script's [`add_option`](http://flask-script.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#adding-options-to-the-manager) method I'm trying to pass the name of a config file into my `create_app()` so I can configure `from_pyfile()` -- [Flask Instance Folders](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#instance-folders)

I used this [gist](https://gist.github.com/smurfix/9307618) to get me started.

`manage.py`

```
from fbone import create_app

app = create_app()
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_option('-c', '--config', dest='config', required=False)
```

`app.py`

```
def create_app(config=None, app_name=None, blueprints=None):
    """Create a Flask app."""

    print config
```

This is just a snippet of my `create_app` function but I'm starting the app like this:

```
$ python manage.py -c config/heroku.cfg runserver
None
/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py:153: UserWarning: Options will be ignored.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
* Restarting with reloader
None
```

As you can see, instead of printing `config/heroku.cfg` it prints `None`
I think this is because of the `UserWarning` from flask script but I can't find out why that's happening.

Comment: OK. According to the docs "For this to work, the manager must be initialized with a factory function rather than a Flask instance.
Otherwise any options you set will be ignored." but I'm already doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out you are creating the flask object by calling `create_app(`) (with the parens).

If you do

```
app=create_app
```

or

```
Manager(create_app)
```

then you should be able to use 
    add_option()

Comment: it defaults to `None` for logical reasons. The `add_option` method should pass the argument following the flag to the `dest` defined, in this case that's `config`. If i'm mistaken, please expand your answer.

Comment: Unless there is some relevant code missing...I'm simply following the flow of code.

You're printing `config` when it is defaulted to None. `add_option` is called AFTER the print statement is executed in `create_app()`.

Comment: `add_option` is not "called" after `create_app`. `create_app` is the application factory passed into manage.py. Flask-Script, (or the `Manager` object) has a set of default commands, like `runserver` which you can `add_option`s to, and it will then instantiate the app (using the factory in this case) and pass those options as the arguments.

Comment: app = create_app() `create the app with no params, printing None for config`
manager = Manager(app) `wrap manager around the app previously created`
manager.add_option('-c', '--config', dest='config', required=False) `add_option called after create_app...`

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. You're talking about the 2nd time None is printed.

Comment: can you provide your complete source for the create_app() method?

Comment: I will but it's not relevant.

Comment: I thought perhaps it was not returning a FLASK object. But it turns out you need to call Manager(create_app) instead of Manager(app). If you pass an instance to Manager() it won't allow options to be used. You have to instead pass the create_app method itself. It's documented in the __init.py__ source. It also correctly reflects what's in the example code you linked to in your question.

Comment: Did you revise your code to call Manager(create_app)?

Comment: had the same problem, OP. The weird thing is that the documentation doesn't point it out very explicitly, even though all the previous examples were like your original code